# Android: how to get a handle on each image while recording from camera

Tags: android

How do I obtain a handle on each image that the camera feeds into your recorder application?

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem? It is exactly what i'm trying to do...

Comment: You can get a handle using the picture callback..check this out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html